# How can pytest obtain the number of executable use cases?

Tags: testing, pytest

### Problem Description

#### background

Hello everyone, I am building a GUI tool for testers based on pytest. I need to obtain the number of use cases to be executed found in the pytest tool to display a Progress bar on the UI. But I encountered some problems when obtaining the number of use cases that need to be executed.

#### Code

I have customized a plugin to obtain the number of executable use cases. The code is as follows

```py
class CaseCountPlugin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_cases_count = 0
    def pytest_collection_modifyitems(self, config, items):
        self.test_cases_count = len(items)
```

When I want to execute the full use case, the plugin works as expected. The number of use cases obtained is consistent with my needs.

When I mark use cases with `@pytest.mark` and execute them hierarchically using the `-m` parameter, the number of use cases obtained is still the number of all use cases. Actually, I want to obtain the actual number of executed use cases.

Execute the `pytest -qq --collect only -m "blocker or critical"` command in CMD, and you will get `36/87 tests collected (51 deselected) in 1.04s`.

The actual number of use cases obtained using the following method is 87, and the number of use cases I want to obtain is 51.

```py
plugin = CaseCountPlugin()
ret = pytest.main(['-qq', '--collect-only', "-m blocker or critical"], plugins=[plugin, allure_plugin])
# Number of test cases used
plugin.test_cases_count
......
```

### My doubts

- Do you know how I should modify the plugin in the previous text?
- Can you recommend some documents or blogs about the use of pytest hook functions?
- Or use other methods to achieve this function? For example, parsing the output of the pytest tool?

If you need to provide additional information, please let me know.

Thank you for reading and looking forward to your reply